# Custom term link return 404 error

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have create a custom post type and a taxonomy while i am clicking on the taxonomy link it returns 404  error,

This how i created the custom post type and taxonomy.

```
function create_post_type_press()
{
    $labels = array('name' => __( 'News', 'example' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'News', 'example' ),
                    // 'add_new' => __( 'Add New Article', 'example' ),
                    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add News', 'example' ),
                    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit News', 'example' ),
                    'new_item' => __( 'New News', 'example' ),
                    'view_item' => __( 'View PNews', 'example' ),
                    'search_items' => __( 'Search News', 'example' ),
                    'not_found' =>  __( 'No News found', 'example' ),
                    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No News found in Trash', 'example' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => '',
                    'menu_name' => 'News');

    $args = array(  'labels' => $labels,
                    'public' => true,
                    'publicly_queryable' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                    'capability_type' => 'post',
                    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/image/settings.png',
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'menu_position' => 90,
                    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', ),
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'news-topic', 'with_front' => false ));
    register_post_type( 'news_article' , $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_press' );  


function news_topic() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
    'topic',  
    'news_article',  
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Topics',  
            'query_var' => true,  
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news-topic')  
        )  
    );  
}
```

and this is for getting the taxonomy link.

```
    function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
        $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
        $output ="<select id='dynamic_select'><option selected class='drop_down'>Default</option>";
        foreach($myterms as $term){
            $root_url = get_bloginfo('url');
            $term_taxonomy=$term->taxonomy;
            $term_slug=$term->slug;
            $term_name =$term->name;
            $link = $term_slug;
            $output .="<option><a href='".$term_link."'>".$term_name."</a></option>";
        }
        $output .="</select>";
    return $output;
    }
    $taxonomies = array('topic');
    $args = array('orderby'=>'count','hide_empty'=>true);
    echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);
```

When i am clicking on the link it goes to `http://domain/news/taxonomy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply dropping slug into `href` field does not make proper URL. You should be using API function to generate correct URL for a term archive - [`get_term_link()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_term_link/).